# can't wget DeviantArt / Pinterest images

Tags: wget

I am trying to scrape some images from DeviantArt and Pintrest for a project of mine using wget and I can't seem to get any images at all. Here is my wget code:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-directories --level=4 --input-file=/path/to/list --accept=jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png --directory-prefix=/path/to/output
```

I was wondering if I could not get this to work because DeviantArt and Pintrest are not static pages but are dynamic using some programming language. Does this affect weget's ability to do its job?

Comment: Maybe these sites are protected from mass download, because your command works with a specific URL: `wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-directories --level=4 --accept=jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png --directory-prefix=/mnt/Storage/test/ http://img07.deviantart.net/005d/i/2017/003/3/0/artoria_pendragon_by_deadxcross-dau2etr.jpg`. But it doesn't work when file name is not mentioned: `wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-directories --level=4 --accept=jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png --directory-prefix=/mnt/Storage/test/ http://img07.deviantart.net/005d/i/2017/003/3/0/`.