# Selected websites can't load under 16.04, but can with debian jenny on raspberry pi

Tags: networking, internet, adsl

Ubuntu user since 12.04, I've always found solutions to my problems here on askubuntu or elsewhere in forums or the net, but this time, after 3 weeks of patiently searching for a solution, testing my hardware in various conditions and trying other systems (e.g raspberry pi, a technician from my ISP also brought his Windrose machine - no problem with Windrose), I decided to ask my first question, because I still can't find a solution, and networking is definitely not my passion (but I'd be pleased to understand better about it).

Here is the situation.

I access to the internet from home with an ADSL, via a USB to ethernet adapter on a notebook. Countless websites I try to access can't load (ex: arduino.cc, yahoo.com, dpreview.com,...) others load normally (gmail, google, stackoverflow related websites...). This is the same for firefox and chrome.

However, if I plug in my raspberry pi with debian Jenny into my ADSL router (having obviously properly setup the connection), I can access all these websites. So this would rule out my ISP.

I also took my notebook to a place where I can access to the internet via both WiFi and ethernet (in the later case, also via the USB to ethernet adapter), and all these impossible-to-load websites can be accessed with no problem. So this would rule out my usb to ethernet adapter.

I had no problem to access these sites on ubuntu 13.10 (I've done a fresh install rather than a distribution upgrade on this machine).

So, given the detail of my system below, what could I do to be able to normally access these websites?
And a side question, why does my rapsberry pi with debian can access websites while a fresh, regularly updated and upgraded 16.04 ubuntu can't (and likely  requires some non obvious fiddling with network settings)?

`$netstat -rn` returns:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         168.63.38.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ppp0
168.63.38.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ppp0
```

`$sudo lshw -C network` returns:

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 24
       serial: c4:85:08:21:f2:7d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-66-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7800000-f7801fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx9cebe8076efa
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:07:6e:fa
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

`ifconfig`:

```
enx9cebe8076efa Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:eb:e8:07:6e:fa  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1f3e:719d:994f:795a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:52336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15400674 (15.4 MB)  TX bytes:9900518 (9.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1262209 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1262209 (1.2 MB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:36.128.152.123  P-t-P:168.63.38.254  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:14959875 (14.9 MB)  TX bytes:8358217 (8.3 MB)
```

And finally:

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ludo-UX32VD

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: I've got similar problem. Both my notebook and desktop PC with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed don't show pictures on [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com) web-site in Firefox browser as well as pictures in Thunderbird e-mail client in messages contained pictures from this site.  The same devices witn Windows 10 and other devices like smartphone and tablet show pictures without problems.

Comment: @VictorA. if you are using ADSL, try setting up the connection with `sudo pppoeconf` (see my answer). Otherwise you would need to provide more information about your own case, and first try some of the solutions found on askubuntu or elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't use ADSL, instead I use TP-LINK WR740N v4 Router (firmware v.3.13.2 Build 140814 Rel.39331n) with all settings set to default. Actually this config allows to load pictures on Pinterest on any other device except Ubuntu-based systems. And so far this is only site I've got problems with. Found something similar but not exactly here: [can't wget DeviantArt / Pinterest images](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867618/cant-wget-deviantart-pinterest-images) but I can see images on DeviantArt. Problem is only with Pinterest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've eventually found a solution: do on ubuntu what I did on raspberry pi: setup my ADSL connection manually using:

`sudo pppoeconf`

(to be installed if not: `sudo apt-get install pppoeconf`)

I accepted the default and recommended options (including that of starting the connection at boot), restarted, and there's no website which can't load so far.

I however don't know how to setup the same via the network manager (eager to test the solution I didn't pay enough attention to the messages when running `pppoeconf`, but there was something about DNS and MSS or MTU).

But now the network manager doesn't show me any connection name, nor any of the other connection I had previously setup (e.g. direct connection to the raspberry pi, ethernet for another network...). That would be the topic of another question if I can't find the answer myself.

There's a reference about pppoeconf:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

And also this informative answer that I hadn't found so far (this post didn't pop up among the dozens of Q&A related to slow internet and web site not loading):

https://askubuntu.com/a/229950/645810